# XML data not being loaded into c# class

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to load data from an XML file into a c# class but am not getting data being loaded in Notifications. The rest of the class (not shown) is correctly populated so I am assuming that my class definition is incorrect. Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
public partial class ISTimetables
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<ISNotification> Notifications { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public partial class ISNotification
{
    public ISNotification()
    {
        On = new List<ISProcessStep>();
        Notify = new List<ISNotify>();
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<ISProcessStep> On { get; set; }

    [XmElement]
    public List<ISNotify> Notify { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public partial class ISNotify
{

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string SimpleEmail { get; set; }
    public string SMS { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]

public enum ISProcessStep
{
    [XmlEnum("Calculated")]
    Calculated,
    [XmlEnum("Reported")]
    Reported,
    [XmlEnum("Customer Approved")]
    CustomerApproved,
    [XmlEnum("Rejected")]
    Rejected
}
```

The data I am trying to load is as follows:

```
<Notifications>
  <Notification>
    <On>Calculated</On>
    <On>Reported</On>
    <Notify SimpleEmail="me@company.com"/>
    <Notify Email="you@company.com"/>
    <Notify SMS="0123456789"/>
  </Notification>

  <Notification>
    <On>Customer Approved</On>
    <Notify Email="him@company.com"/>
  </Notification>
</Notifications>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILEName = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ISTimetables));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILEName);
            ISTimetables tables = (ISTimetables)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Notifications")]
    public partial class ISTimetables
    {
        [XmlElement("Notification")]
        public List<ISNotification> Notifications { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Notification")]
    public partial class ISNotification
    {
        public ISNotification()
        {
            On = new List<ISProcessStep>();
            Notify = new List<ISNotify>();
        }

        [XmlElement]
        public List<ISProcessStep> On { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public List<ISNotify> Notify { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public partial class ISNotify
    {

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string SimpleEmail { get; set; }
        public string SMS { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]

    public enum ISProcessStep
    {
        [XmlEnum("Calculated")]
        Calculated,
        [XmlEnum("Reported")]
        Reported,
        [XmlEnum("Customer Approved")]
        CustomerApproved,
        [XmlEnum("Rejected")]
        Rejected
    }
}
```